# How to run Ubuntu natively on Macbook?

Tags: dual-boot, macosx

So I have Macbook Pro 13” 2015. It is really old. Tried to sell it off but not getting good price. So I want to use my Macbook for Ubuntu only. Is it possible to have just UbuntuOS on Macbook without MacOS.
If yes, kindly tell me the steps as I am an amateur in techy stuff. Ciao

Comment: Yes, it's possible. [Follow the official installation instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) to create the USB key and install. For Step 4, you will need to hold down the [Option] key after the boot chime in order to boot from the USB device. When the installer asks, wipe the system clean and install Ubuntu. Be sure to have a USB⇢Ethernet dongle handy, though, as you will not have working WiFi until you install some drivers manually afterwards.

Comment: If you don't have an internet dongle, you can also use your phone for tethering.